# Sanitize ChildProcess arguments in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, process, command, arguments

I have the need to launch a childprocess in Node.js like this

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

var execParams = [
    '--nameParam',
    userName
]

exec([PATH-TO-EXE], execParams, {timeout: 30000}, function (err, data) {
    ...
});
```

This is a made up example of what I've already tested and is working. The user input (userName) is entered as the value of the parameter '--nameParam', and it works great. But how do I sanitize userName since comes from a text input field (it is unsafe user-entered data)?

Is there any way to make sure this is just a string? And even if it is just a string, it still could contain dangerous characters, couldn't it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just make sure it only has `[a-zA-Z]` in it (or any additional characters allowed in a username, but safe in a command line).

Comment: That occurred to me, but what if it is possible to still execute commands with just purely letters?

Comment: That depends entirely upon your command line and what program you're running and what it can do.  Plain letters can't trigger anything untoward in the OS - they are just a command line argument to be passed to your program as a string.  No harm there.  You should probably make sure there are no potentially unsafe characters like `[<>|/\:&]`, etc...  That's why I said to limit to only known safe characters that no OS will treat as anything other than another character in a command line argument.  Start with only the chars allowed in a username and then remove anything that could be unsafe.

Comment: I see what you mean. So really the danger is limited by what the exe I am launching takes as parameters? If so I could look through the parameters for that exe and see if I need to block text that might cause one of those parameters to be selected by the user's input. But yes, I will definitely remove the unsafe characters too.

Comment: I suppose one of my worries was if the user managed to chain a command and therefore do something entirely separate. But if symbols like "&" and ";" are blocked I would think that should take care of that worry.

Comment: Because of the way `execFile()` works, I'm not even sure you have exposure to that because it's not a full-on command line that the OS parses from scratch.  It's just a list of arguments sent directly to the child process.  But, to be safe, you can certainly filter out anything that "might" have any potentially dangerous angle to it.

Comment: Good thought, I didn't realize that. Thanks very much!